# Is it possible to reset the compass calibration to factory settings?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, compass, calibration

My Samsung Galaxy S6 indicates constantly the wrong direction in Maps, compass apps, etc. as it shows the North always towards the left side of the phone. (This might be a long-term effect of the magnetic phone case.) Compass calibration is reported as "very good" and re-calibrating the compass by moving the phone in a 8-figure pattern doesn't have any effect.

Is it possible to somehow reset the compass calibration to factory settings?

Comment: Maybe you can find a configuration file and delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully, it looks like removing the phone from the magnetic case and re-calibrating it fixed the issue.

I've thrown the magnetic case on the bottom of a closet and I'm never using it again.

Answer (score 0):

I also had another problem, if I tried to pay with NFC it sometimes gave me errors.

I have removed the two magnets by making an incision with a cutter, in the back and front cover, so that I can still use the cover.

Samsung A8 2018 user.